# How can I combine only pinned taskbar icons?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

Under `Taskbar Settings`, I currently have the `Combine taskbar buttons` option set to `Never`.

I'm wondering if I can somehow combine only **pinned** items, but have everything else uncombined.

So the end result taskbar would look similar to this even if I had several instances of pinned items open:

[image]

Currently when I open a pinned item, the icon is immediately expanded to show text, and additional instances do not stack on top of eachother:

[image]

I find this very frustrating as it basically defeats the purpose of why I pinned the items in the first place.

I know it's a long-shot, but if somebody has a solution I would super grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with native Windows 10. I know that there was a program called 7+ Taskbar Tweaker that used to do this for Windows 7 and 8, but there were problems for Windows 10. I do see that the latest version mentions it should work under Windows 10 though, but I haven't tested it.

See also: [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)

Comment: I'd be fine with using a third-party program. I will take a look at Taskbar Tweaker, thanks.

Comment: While checking things out, it seems that they added support for Windows 10. I stopped using it, so I'm not sure how well it works now, but it was great under Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this answer sooner. I don't check here too often... :)

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for thinking about it and accepting. :)